# Query explaination

Tags: mysql, sql

I recently started learning SQL and wanted to see if someone could give me a quick overview of this query and how tell me if my implementation would be correct. The part where I lack the knowledge is the "check" statement
Query is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE
  partner_pricing
ADD
  partner_description VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL CHECK (partner_description IN ('Direct', 'Reseller'));
----------------------------------------------------
// Html

<form>
  <select>
    <option value="Reseller">Reseller</option>
    <option value="Direct">Direct</option>
  </select>
 </form>
```

Many thanks.

Comment: How can we tell if implementation is correct if we don't know what are you trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I want to give the user 1 of 2 options, whether they will be reseller or a direct customer of the product. I assume the rest of my form is unimportant as it has no direct impact on this selection. This is simply for organization purposes. I'm just confused as to the Check(partner_description IN ('direct','resller')) portion.

Comment: Ah ok, appreciate that information. 

Any recommendation to how i could modify my query If i want a column in my table to only have the options of reseller / direct user?

Comment: Just posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ah ok, appreciate that information. Any recommendation to how i could modify my query If i want a column in my table to only have the options of reseller / direct user?

### Use enums

```sql
ALTER TABLE
  partner_pricing
ADD
  partner_description ENUM ('Direct','Reseller')
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is kind a broad but I would tell you the considerations I made.

First you need a table for your options lest call it `partner_description`

```
partner_description_id (pk) description
         1                    Reseller
         2                    Direct
```

Having a separated table allow you made changes to the "options" without affect your application. If you want show the options on your page you do:

```
  SELECT * FROM partner_description
```

The HTML should looks like

```
<select>
  <option value="1">Reseller</option>
  <option value="2">Direct</option>
</select>
```

In your table `partner_pricing` you will have `partner_description_id` with FK constraint. That will validate you won’t insert any wrong value. Also, because you save the id instead of the string you save fewer data and if you change the description don't have to change the all data.